# Integrate git into an existing project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I want to integrate `git` into an existing project created using eclipse IDE.

Currently, I have the project on location: `z:\workspace\myProject`

But there are some files and folders that I DON'T want to track with `git` like:

```
z:\workspace\myProject\images

z:\workspace\myProject\static_info.txt

z:\workspace\myProject\static_info_class.class
```

How do I add git to this environment without breaking the project, which is running fine?

Also the `git` repository has already been created on remote server having url as : `https://<username>@<server_location.com>:<port>/parent_dir/myproject.git`

So I want to checkin my project in `git` repository which is already existing using eclipse IDE.

I have installed EGIT in my eclipse IDE.

**Note:** I don't want to `clone` the project into new workspace and place my working project into newly created location `<somepath>\myproject` then commit and push whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Git bash?

If yes, go to the location z:/workspace/

```
git init
```

add *.jpeg, *.txt and *.class in your .gitignore file

then add the project related files to your stage

```
git add .
```

and then commit your code locally using

```
git commit -m "Your Custom Commit Messages"
```

then to push your code to the remote do the below

```
git remote add origin https://<username>@<server_location.com>:<port>/parent_dir/myproject.git

git push origin master
```

You can verify your current project in remote using the command

```
git remote -v
```

I am sure EGIT can also help you do the above steps. I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: using EGIT please try the steps 1. Create a new local Git repo. (browse and select the z:/workspace) 2. Right click on the Git repo and select Commit. 3. Right click on Git repo and Remote -> Push

Comment: I followed all the steps and executed the commands successfully, but I am not getting my project code in remote server location. Are we missing something??

Comment: @Farooque - Sorry to have missed one important step. **git push origin master**. Edited the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

In a existing project in Eclipse you have to right click on the project and the go to Team -> Share Project -> Git.

After that you will get in Eclipse all options provided by Git.
There you can also "ignore" files right click on them and going to "Team" option.

I hope it helps.